# how can i downgrade my flutter version to 3.7.5 version for a specific project

Tags: flutter, version, fvm

I need to open a project which is built using flutter sdk version 3.7.5 but currenly im using 3.13.6 version therefore i causing more errors in packages

please provide a way to open that project but im working in two projects so i dont want to totally downgrade the version

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.  [Puro](https://puro.dev).  Installs multiple versions of flutter efficiently. You can choose a version for the default commands, as well as a per-project version.

If anyone answers "fvm", that's less efficient and capable.  I stopped using FVM six months ago, now that Puro is here.

Comment: thanks, I tried with fvm but got some errors, Ill try with Puro then

Answer (score 0):

I use fvm often for work and personal projects. In my experience fvm is smart enough that you DO NOT have to run `fvm use {Flutter version}` for each Flutter project with a different version.

Make sure you run `fvm install {Flutter version}` if you don't have the version installed already(`fvm list` to see installed versions). If you are in the project directory you can run `fvm install` and fvm will install the correct version for you automatically.

As for the errors, I'm assuming it is something to do with Flutter itself. I would start with a `fvm flutter clean`. Editing your answer and posting the error could narrow it down. Hope this helps!